# automated login to remote website using curl php

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I'm newbie for the concept ***CURL***. Now I'm trying to do the remote login to facebook using php curl. I have referred [Refer](http://www.binarytides.com/remote-login-with-curl-php/),[Refer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814158/post-to-a-facebook-users-wall-with-curl-php?answertab=active#tab-top),[Refer 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194407/login-to-remote-url-using-curl-php),[Refer 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130449/remote-login-to-facebook-account).But it does not clear my doubt.

My code follows here:

```
 define('HOME' , dirname(__FILE__));

 //Create a curl object
 $ch = curl_init();
 if(is_callable('curl_init')){
     echo "Enabled"."<br>";
   }
  else
   {
     echo "Not enabled"."</br>";
   }

    $login_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/login/';

    //These are the post data username and password
    $post_data = array('email'=>'MY_EMAIL_ID','pass'=>'gdfgg');

    //Set the useragent
    $agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
    //echo $agent;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

    //Set the URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url );

    //This is a POST query
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );

    //Set the post data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

    //We want the content after the query
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //Follow Location redirects
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    /*
    Set the cookie storing files
    Cookie files are necessary since we are logging and session data needs to be saved
    */

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  HOME. '/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,  HOME. '/cookie.txt');

    //Execute the action to login
    $postResult = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    echo $postResult;
```

When I checked in my firefox DOM section,it shows
[image]

In my cookie.txt, I have no code in that,it stands empty even though I changed the permission to all.

**Question 1 :** What the above code will do?

**Question 2 :** How can I check its working or not in DOM?

**Question 3 :** It will work in local?

Comment: Are you looking for login using Facebook? (Or social network login API's)

Comment: yes login facebook using curl

Comment: why would you do that via curl? just create a proper login and store an access token.

Comment: Ji i'm just learning,how to login facebook without going to facebook page by using curl

Comment: That's not allowed IMHO.

Comment: Facebook is actively taking measures against this. If you want to learn how cURL works, then choose another “target”.

Comment: @CBroe ok ji....thanks for your concern

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will never accepts any request without an authentication (OAuth) & APP conf's.

Below will give you some idea about developing Login for your website using facebook.

As developer login in facebook :

Also, You should refer to

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.3

You have to create your APP first `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '{your-app-id}',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually i'm learning about curl.I want to do a thing like [Link](http://www.binarytides.com/remote-login-with-curl-php/) this.

Comment: First you have to understand, how to configure your App in facebook dev. Then start writing code.

Comment: I'm not creating any app to configure ji...i just practicing by doing this,